# Is it possible to pass an integer to a precision specifier for string

Tags: c

I was wondering if it is possible to pass an integer as a precision specifier.

For example if

```
 static void ShouldBeTruncated( char * StringToCheck, int precision )
{
  (strlen( StringToCheck )>= precision) ? printf( "%.15s...", StringToCheck) : printf( "%s", StringToCheck)  ;
}
```

Is it even possible to replace `%.15s` with `%.<<PRECISION GOES HERE >>s` so the length of precision could be specified ? 
If it is possible, how to do it ?

Comment: printf("%*.*f\n",10,5,123.456);

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `*` as the precision, which takes another `int` argument off the argument list (before the argument whose value is to be printed):

```
void prec_print(double d, int prec)
{ 
    printf("%.*f\n", prec, d);
}
```

(Similarly, the field width may be specified dynamically by using `*`, too: `%*.*f, width, prec, val`.)

Comment: [Demo](https://ideone.com/TvPkdy)

Comment: Thanks your solution works like a charm